# Why is the size of make_shared two pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

As illustrated in the code [here](http://ideone.com/dZbvK), the size of the object returned from make_shared is two pointers.

However, why doesn't `make_shared` work like the following (assume T is the type we're making a shared pointer to):

> The result of `make_shared` is **one** pointer in size, which points to of allocated memory of size `sizeof(int) + sizeof(T)`, where the int is a reference count, and this gets incremented and decremented on construction/destruction of the pointers.

`unique_ptr`s are only the size of one pointer, so I'm not sure why shared pointer needs two. As far as I can tell, all it needs a reference count, which with `make_shared`, can be placed with the object itself.

Also, is there any implementation that is implemented the way I suggest (without having to muck around with `intrusive_ptr`s for particular objects)? If not, what is the reason why the implementation I suggest is avoided?

Comment: Side note: The `count` is not just a count, there is at the very least two counts, one for the `shared_ptr`s, and another one for the `weak_ptr`s. Depending on the implementation there might be some extra memory in use.

Comment: @David: Why the need to count `weak_ptr`s? I thought the point of a `weak_ptr` is to break cycles, so `weak_ptr` references do not keep a object alive (hence, I don't see the need to maintain a reference count of them).

Comment: @Clinton: `weak_ptr` need access to the count to be able to determine whether the object is still alive or the last `shared_ptr` went away and the object has been deleted. That means that the `count` object must be kept alive as long as there is at least one `weak_ptr` that refers to it. The second count does not control lifetime of the object, but lifetime of the count itself. As James correctly points out, in `std::shared_ptr` (or `boost::shared_ptr`) the `count` object also owns the deleter, so that is one more piece of information to keep outside of the original object.

Comment: @David: I see, thanks for the explanation of `weak_ptr`, though I still can't see why objects from `make_shared` need two pointers, as I believe their difference would be a compile time constant (besides the standard perhaps requiring them to be the same type).

Comment: @Clinton: Ok, lets follow that rationale: assume that `make_shared` returned an object of a type `MS` that held a single pointer. The type itself has knowledge of the offset (it knows how much space is required by the `count`). Now, the use of `make_shared` is: `shared_ptr<X> p = make_shared<Y>();` (or any variant). `make_shared` would create a `MS` object that holds a single pointer. The very next step is the initialization of `p`, which would convert the `MS` temporary into a `shared_ptr` with 2 pointers.  Now, why would you create a type `MS` in the first place? There is no real gain.

Comment: @David: With `make_shared` you don't get to specify a deleter. That's part of the reason that it's more efficient, because it just uses the allocator for the entire refcontrol-plus-object block. A great description of the interals of `shared_ptr` can be found in [STL #1](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Advanced-STL-1-of-n).

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I don't think I follow how your comment, or how it relates to my comments. The `shared_ptr` **needs** the deleter, and *yes*, you could create a different type in `make_shared` that is implicitly convertible to `shared_ptr`, and you can make that type have a single pointer, but the lifetime of that object will be *very short*: the very first thing that is done with the result of `make_shared` is assign it to (or initialize) a `shared_ptr` which requires the extra pointer. At the end of the `shared_ptr` lifetime it will call the *deleter*.

Comment: ... unless you intend to have the result of `make_shared` incompatible with `shared_ptr`. At the end of the expression, the `shared_ptr` has to be a `shared_ptr`, with `deleter` and all. (There is no alternative: either at the end of the expression you get a `shared_ptr` with all that is required by the `shared_ptr` or you don't)

Comment: @David: I'm a bit confused myself now, but what I wanted to point out is that not every shared pointer has a deleter. The count object is polymorphic and has an abstract "delete" function, but that one is implemented differently in the three concrete cases "default" (call `delete`), "custom deleter" (call custom deleter) and "make_shared" (`delete` entire control block).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In all implementations I'm aware of, `shared_ptr` stores the owned pointer and the reference count **in the same memory block**.  This is contrary to what other answers are saying.  Additionally a copy of the pointer will be stored in the `shared_ptr` object.  [N1431](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1431.htm#Memory-footprint) describes the typical memory layout.

It is true that one can build a reference counted pointer with sizeof only one pointer.  But `std::shared_ptr` contains features that absolutely demand a sizeof two pointers.  One of those features is this constructor:

```
template<class Y> shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *p) noexcept;

    Effects: Constructs a shared_ptr instance that stores p
             and shares ownership with r.

    Postconditions: get() == p && use_count() == r.use_count()
```

One pointer in the `shared_ptr` is going to point to the control block owned by `r`.  This control block is going to contain *the owned pointer*, which does not have to be `p`, and typically isn't `p`.  The other pointer in the `shared_ptr`, the one returned by `get()`, is going to be `p`.

This is referred to as *aliasing support* and was introduced in [N2351](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2351.htm#aliasing).  You may note that `shared_ptr` had a sizeof two pointers prior to the introduction of this feature.  Prior to the introduction of this feature, one could possibly have implemented `shared_ptr` with a sizeof one pointer, but no one did because it was impractical.  After [N2351](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2351.htm#aliasing), it became impossible.

One of the reasons it was impractical prior to [N2351](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2351.htm#aliasing) was because of support for:

```
shared_ptr<B> p(new A);
```

Here, `p.get()` returns a `B*`, and has generally forgotten all about the type `A`.  The only requirement is that `A*` be convertible to `B*`.  `B` may derive from `A` using multiple inheritance.  And this implies that the value of the pointer itself may change when converting from `A` to `B` and vice-versa.  In this example, `shared_ptr<B>` needs to remember two things:

1. How to return a `B*` when `get()` is called.
2. How to delete a `A*` when it is time to do so.

A very nice implementation technique to accomplish this is to store the `B*` in the `shared_ptr` object, and the `A*` within the control block with the reference count.

Comment: Ok. This explains why `shared_ptr` deletes object correctly even if the destructor of B is not virtual. (this is for the case `shared_ptr<B> p(new A);` and `class A : B;`)

Answer (score 4):

The reference count cannot be stored in a `shared_ptr`. `shared_ptr`s have to share the reference count among the various instances, therefore the `shared_ptr` must have a pointer to the reference count. Also, `shared_ptr` (the result of `make_shared`) does not *have* to store the reference count in the same allocation that the object was allocated in.

The point of `make_shared` is to prevent the allocation of two blocks of memory for `shared_ptr`s. Normally, if you just do `shared_ptr<T>(new T())`, you have to allocate memory for the reference count in addition to the allocated `T`. `make_shared` puts this all in one allocation block, using placement new and delete to create the `T`. So you only get one memory allocation and one deletion.

But `shared_ptr` must still have the *possibility* of storing the reference count in a different block of memory, since using `make_shared` is not required. Therefore it needs two pointers.

Really though, this shouldn't bother you. Two pointers isn't that much space, even in 64-bit land. You're still getting the important part of `intrusive_ptr`'s functionality (namely, not allocating memory twice).

---

Your question seems to be "why should `make_shared` return a `shared_ptr` instead of some other type?" There are many reasons.

`shared_ptr` is intended to be a kind of default, catch-all smart pointer. You might use a unique_ptr or scoped_ptr for cases where you're doing something special. Or just for temporary memory allocations at function scope. But `shared_ptr` is intended to be the sort of thing you use for any serious reference counted work.

Because of that, `shared_ptr` would be part of an interface. You would have functions that take `shared_ptr`. You would have functions that return `shared_ptr`. And so on.

Enter `make_shared`. Under your idea, this function would return some new kind of object, a `make_shared_ptr` or whatever. It would have its own equivalent to `weak_ptr`, a `make_weak_ptr`. But despite the fact that these two sets of types would share the *exact same interface*, you could not use them together.

Functions that take a `make_shared_ptr` could not take a `shared_ptr`. You might make `make_shared_ptr` convertible to a `shared_ptr`, but you couldn't go the other way around. You wouldn't be able to take any `shared_ptr` and turn it into a `make_shared_ptr`, because `shared_ptr` *needs* to have two pointers. It can't do its job without two pointers.

So now you have two sets of pointers which are half-incompatible. You have one-way conversions; if you have a function that returns a `shared_ptr`, the user had better be using a `shared_ptr` instead of a `make_shared_ptr`.

Doing this for the sake of a pointer's worth of space is simply not worthwhile. Creating this incompatibility, creating two sets of pointers just for 4 bytes? That simply isn't worth the trouble that is caused.

Now, perhaps you would ask, "if you have `make_shared_ptr` why would you ever need `shared_ptr` at all?"

Because `make_shared_ptr` is insufficient. `make_shared` is not the only way to create a `shared_ptr`. Maybe I'm working with some C-code. Maybe I'm using SQLite3. `sqlite3_open` returns a `sqlite3*`, which is a database connection.

Right now, using the right destructor functor, I can store that `sqlite3*` in a `shared_ptr`. That object will be reference counted. I can use `weak_ptr` where necessary. I can play all the tricks I normally would with a regular C++ `shared_ptr` that I get from `make_shared` or whatever other interface. And it would work perfectly.

But if `make_shared_ptr` exists, then that doesn't work. Because I *can't* create one of them from that. The `sqlite3*` has already been allocated; I can't ram it through `make_shared`, because `make_shared` *constructs* an object. It doesn't work with already existing ones.

Oh sure, I could do some hack, where I bundle the `sqlite3*` in a C++ type who's destructor will destroy it, then use `make_shared` to create that type. But then using it becomes much more complicated: you have to go through another level of indirection. And you have to go through the trouble of making a type and so forth; the destructor method above at least can use a simple lambda function.

Proliferation of smart pointer types is something to be avoided. You need an immobile one, a movable one, and a copyable shared one. And one more to break circular references from the latter. If you start to have multiple ones of those types, then you either have very special needs or you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I now understand there is no technical reason for a shared_ptr from make_shared_ptr to have two pointers, besides compatibility with other shared_ptrs. I guess we could have 3 shared_ptrs, the default one, the one I mentioned, and one with one pointer with a pointer to the object stored in the control block. Converting between all of them could get confusing.

Comment: "_these two sets of types would share the exact same interface,_" Wrong. `make_shared_ptr` couldn't support aliasing (in particular, arbitrary casting). `make_shared` is irrelevant here.

Comment: @curiousguy: You know, you could have just edited the post and changed "share the exact same interface" to "have virtually identical interfaces". No need for the down-vote.

Comment: Hug? You want me to edit your answer to remove every mention of `make_shared`??? Aliasing is a very important functionality of `shared_ptr`. And BTW, `weak_ptr` doesn't "break cycles" and isn't even a smart pointer. And I don't agree that "_Proliferation of smart pointer types is something to be avoided._". OTOH, proliferation of smart pointer types that are used in interfaces and have the same purpose with a very slightly different space/time trade-of is to be avoided.

Comment: I also strongly disagree with "_`shared_ptr` is intended to be a kind of default ... pointer_". The default should be `unique_ptr`, unless you really need `shared_ptr`.

Comment: For example, I feel the need for a family of `shared_ptr` with a Deleter template parameter.

Comment: @curiousguy: I think you're misunderstanding what Clinton was asking about. He was asking why the pointer type that `make_shared` returns is a `shared_ptr` and not some other kind of pointer which could be smaller (one pointer in size rather than two). `make_shared` is thus an important part of any answer to that question, so it is most certainly not irrelevant. The part you were concerned with was the "exact same interface" part, not the relevance of `make_shared`.

Comment: @curiousguy: What exactly is "wrong" about his question? I don't agree with his belief that it should return something else, but there's nothing wrong with asking why it doesn't. And most important of all, if you think his question is "wrong", why are you arguing with _me_ about _my_ answer to his question? `make_shared` is indeed relevant, because that's what he asked about. If you don't like what Clinton asked about, take it up with him.

Comment: "_What exactly is "wrong" about his question?_" The question is (implicitly) incorrect: it mentions `make_shared`, implicitly opposed to `shared_ptr<T>(new T)`, which is not the real issue. "`make_shared` _is indeed relevant, because that's what he asked about._" Actually he wants to know why there isn't a single word shared smart pointer. The answer is that it is possible, but this shared smart pointer type would not allow the arbitrary pointer conversions allowed by `shared_ptr`.

Comment: _The answer is that it is possible, but this shared smart pointer type would not allow the arbitrary pointer conversions allowed by 'shared_ptr'_ This is wrong. These requirements are possible with a single word shared pointer, only impractical in the general case. 'make_shared' however is not the general case and would make an efficient implementation possible.

Answer (score 2):

I have a [`honey::shared_ptr`](https://github.com/Qarterd/Honeycomb/blob/master/src/common/Honey/Memory/SharedPtr.h) implementation that automatically optimizes to a size of 1 pointer when intrusive.  It's conceptually simple -- types that inherit from `SharedObj` have an embedded control block, so in that case `shared_ptr<DerivedSharedObj>` is intrusive and can be optimized.  It unifies `boost::intrusive_ptr` with non-intrusive pointers like `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`.

This optimization is only possible because I don't support aliasing (see Howard's answer). The result of `make_shared` can then have 1 pointer size if `T` is known to be intrusive at compile-time. But what if `T` is known to be non-intrusive at compile-time? In this case it's impractical to have 1 pointer size as `shared_ptr` must behave generically to support control blocks allocated both alongside and separately from their objects.  With only 1 pointer the generic behavior would be to point to the control block, so to get at `T*` you'd have to first dereference the control block which is impractical.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already said that `shared_ptr` needs two pointers because it has to point to the reference count memory block and the Pointed to Types memory Block.

I guess what you are asking is this:

When using `make_shared` both memory blocks are merged into one, and because the blocks sizes and alignment are known and fixed at compile time one pointer could be calculated from the other (because they have a fixed offset). So why doesn't the standard or boost create a second type like `small_shared_ptr` which does only contain one pointer.
Is that about right?

Well the answer is that if you think it through it quickly becomes a large hassle for very little gain. How do you make the pointers compatible? One direction, i.e. assigning a `small_shared_ptr` to a `shared_ptr` would be easy, the other way round extremely hard. Even if you solve this problem efficiently, the small efficiency you gain will probably be lost by the to-and-from conversions that will inevitably sprinkle up in any serious program. And the additional pointer type also makes the code that uses it harder to understand.

Comment: As others have said, this has nothing to do with `make_shared`.

Comment: What @Nicol says. 'make_shared' is highly relevant to the question that was asked, and my answer and Nicols are both correct, 'make_shared' could return a shared pointer that has only one pointer, and the reason why it is not done is that it needs to be compatible with 'shared_ptr' which has further requirements which make this impractical, or as Howard explained even impossible.

Comment: If you drop support for pointer conversions (implicit derived to base or explicit casts), all Howard' arguments disappear. Then you can have `sizeof(shared_ptr<T*>) == sizeof(T*)`.

Comment: If you read @Howard 's answer carefully you will find that the only requirement that cannot be fulfilled with a "one ptr" smart pointer is Aliasing, which - to come back to the original question - cannot be done with 'make_shared' anyway. All other requirements can be fulfilled, albeit in an impractical (i.e. less efficient or harder to implement) way.